# Unexpected error when creating a friend template function

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading, friend-function

guys I am trying to create a template for my class SortedList. I want to overload the << operator, so I declare a friend function inside the class but every time I try to compile the main.cpp I get the following error:
 template-id 'operator<< ... ' does not match any template declaration.
here you the code from main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    SortedList<int, int> lst, lst2;
    int a = 2;
    lst.addItem(2, 3);
    cout << lst << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this is the template class declaration and definition

```
template <typename K, typename V>
struct Node
{
    K key;
    V value;
    Node<K, V>* next;
};
template <typename K, typename V>
class SortedList
{
friend ostream& operator << <K, V>(ostream&, const SortedList&);
public:

    SortedList();
    SortedList(const SortedList&);
    SortedList& operator = (const SortedList&);
    ~SortedList();

    void addItem(const K&, const V&);
    void removeElem(const K&);
    void removeAt(int);
    bool remove(const K&);


private:

    Node<K, V>* start;
    size_t n;

};
```

Comment: `friend ostream& operator << <K, V>(ostream&, const SortedList&);`: if you use such syntax you should declare `operator <<` template before the `SortedList` class template definition and after its forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can find a good explanation on [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html) perhaps I'll quote it:

> The snag happens when the compiler sees the friend lines way up in the
>   class definition proper. At that moment it does not yet know the
>   friend functions are themselves templates.
>
> When you call the operator+
>   or operator<< functions, this assumption causes the compiler to
>   generate a call to the non-template functions, but the linker will
>   give you an "undefined external" error because you never actually
>   defined those non-template functions.

One solution is to put:

```
template<typename K, typename V> class SortedList;
template<typename K, typename V> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const SortedList<K,V>& x);
```

On top, [Here](http://ideone.com/FdkF8k) is an example for you class (that compiles perfectly, just does nothing).